# Customised printing page size css not working in windows system

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a customized page size for my software, I wrote code that works fine in Ubuntu but in windows system, it changes the paper size to latter automatically.

Here is my css,

```
@media print{
  @page{
      size: 255mm 120mm;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 0px;
  }
}
#mtable
{
  page-break-after: always;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Can anybody help me out from this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, I copied the page size out side of @print.

```
@media print{
  @page{
      size: 255mm 120mm;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 0px;
  }
}
@page{
    size: 255mm 120mm;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```